# Basic MATLAB variable manipulation

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a `dwc = [3001 x 2 double]` which more or less is a sin function, I have a `for` loop finding top values in `dwc(:,2)`. Lets say that there is a top value in `dwc(531,2)` which way is best way or what is easy to take `dwc(531,1)` and `dwc(531,2)` and make an `M =  [num_of_top_points x 2 double]`?

For the following loop, what do I do?

```
j = 0;
for i = 2:size(dwcL01,1)-1
    if dwcL01(i,2) > dwcL01(i-1,2) && dwcL01(i,2) > dwcL01(i+1,2)
        j = j+1;
        ?? = dwcL01(i,:);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you complete your loop

```
j = 0;
M = [];
for i = 2:size(dwcL01,1)-1
    if dwcL01(i,2) > dwcL01(i-1,2) && dwcL01(i,2) > dwcL01(i+1,2)
        j = j+1;
        M(j, :) = dwcL01(i, :);
    end
end
```

But you could do this much more efficiently by vectorizing

```
%//Some example data
x = -4*pi:0.5:4*pi;
y = cos(x);
dwcL01 = [x(:), y(:)]; %// (:) just makes it a column

%// Finding the peaks using diff and sign. Note that I add the first element to the beginning as diff reduces the size by one so this prevents offsetting
F = diff(sign(diff([dwcL01(1,2);dwcL01(:,2)]))) < 0;
M = [dwcL01(F,:)', dwcL01(F,:)'];    

plot(x, y, M(:,1), M(:,2), '*r')
```

[image]

How that works is first we find the difference of each element consecutive element pair. Now when the sign changes, that means we've hit a max or min. If the sign change is negative then the gradient went from positive to negative which is a max. So I use `diff(sign())` to find the points where the sign changes and then `> 0` to create a logical matrix with false everywhere expect for the max. Then I use logical indexing to extract the max.

Comment: Cloud you edit you answer with an example of how to vectorizing it?

Comment: @MaltheEisum This will work fine on a numerical model?? `cos(x)` is just a vector of number, it is numerical. That's the default for Matlab.

Comment: @MaltheEisum That really shouldn't be a problem. Just try run the code. If your loop works, then the `diff` solution will also work

Answer (score 1):

You could append it to a matrix (let's call it `dwcL01_max`) - this isn't the fastest way because the matrix size changes each loop but it works:

```
dwcL01_max = [dwcL01_max dwcL01(i,:)];
```

The other option would be to use the builtin `findpeaks` (from the signal proc toolbox)

```
[~, dwcL01_peaks] = findpeaks(dwcL01(:,2));
dwcL01_max = dwcL01(dwcL01_peaks, :);
```